# Is the sequence $f_n(x)=\frac{x^{2n}}{1+x^{2n}}$ uniformly convergent?

Tags: analysis, uniform-convergence

> Given $R\in\mathbb{R}$, $R>1$  investigate the sequence of functions $(f_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$, given by
>   $$f_n(x)=\frac{x^{2n}}{1+x^{2n}}, \qquad x \in\ [R,\infty)$$
>    with regard to uniform convergence.

Could someone help me with this problem?  I got that the limit of $f_n(x)$ converges to $1$. But does this mean, that $f_n(x)$ is not pointwise convergent and that's why also not uniformly convergent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question has been edited.

$f_n(x)$ converges point-wise to $1$. $|f_n(x)-1|=\frac 1 {1+x^{2}n} \leq \frac 1{1+R^{2}n}$ and $\frac 1 {1+R^{2}n} \to 0$. Hence the convergence is uniform.

Answer for the revised version:

$f_n(x)$ converges point-wise to $1$. $|f_n(x)-1|=\frac 1 {1+x^{2n}} \leq \frac 1{1+R^{2n}}$ and $\frac 1 {1+R^{2n}} \to 0$. Hence the convergence is uniform.

Comment: But in order a sequence of functions to be pointwisely convergent $lim f_n (x)= f(x)$. So we have that $lim f_n (x) = 1$ and $ f(x) =0,5 $

Comment: $f_n(x)=\frac {x^{2}} {1/n+x^{2}} \to \frac {x^{2}} {x^{2}}=1$ for all $x \geq R$. Let $f(x)=1$ for all $x$. Then we have proved that $f_n(x) \to f(x)$ for all $x$. @Kai

Comment: how you get that $f(x) =1$ , then when we plug $x=1$ we  have $\frac {1^{2n}}{1+1^{2n}}= 0.5$

Comment: Did you type $x^{2}n$ for $x^{2n}$ That makes a big difference.  @Kai

Comment: oh, I am sorry I mean $x^{2n}$

Comment: @Kai $x=1$ is not allowed. We are considering only points $x \geq R$ where $R>1$.

Comment: but why pointwise, even if I plug $x=2$ in $f(x)$ I won't get 1 but $0,8$

Comment: After putting $x=2$ did to take limit as $n \to \infty$ or just take one particular value of $n$? What we need  is $\lim_{n \to \infty} f_n(x)=1$ for all $x$. This is true for $x=2$ also.